# Apex describe custom field to get picklist values

Tags: apex

I need to get a list of available picklist fields in apex code, I attempted to get them like so:

```
// Products__c is a multi-select picklist custom activity field
Event.Products__c.getDescribe().getPicklistValues()
```

And this works fine in anonymous apex execution but when I do it in my apex class, it wont compile giving me the following syntax error:

`Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getDescribe() from the type String`

Why does it work fine in anonymous apex but not in my class? And how should I be getting picklist values in apex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have another symbol in the context of your class that is called `Event` and is shadowing the system `Event` class. Since that symbol has a property `Products__c` of type `String`, you may have a variable declaration like `Event Event`. For example, this code fails the same way in Anonymous Apex:

```
Event Event = null;

System.debug(Event.Description.getDescribe());
```

Remove the shadowing symbol and the code will work.

Comment: Alternatively reference the describe using `Schema.Event.MyField__c...`.

Comment: I do have a field `event` of type `Event`; are variables not case sensitive? Either way you seem to be right; `Event` was shadowed.

Comment: The vast majority of Apex (including symbol references) is not case sensitive.